# Bot Framework not able to authenticate with Enterprise Bot

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm currently using the Enterprise Bot template and I cannot complete the authentication dialog. Every time I try to call it, it reaches the token post back and then stops execution. It’s not hitting the getToken methods further in the waterfall (i.e. I can sign in and I get the magic code, but when I paste it in the emulator to continue authentication the dialog stops).

I have tried the AuthenticationBot sample from github and that works fine. I think it has something to do with the routerDialog and/or my OnTurnAsync method but I have no idea what it could be.
Edit:

```
AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialDialogId, authenticate));
AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(DialogIds.LoginPrompt, new OAuthPromptSettings()
            {
                ConnectionName = ConnectionName,
                Title = AuthenticationStrings.TITLE,
                Text = AuthenticationStrings.PROMPT,
            }));
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptToLogin(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await sc.PromptAsync(AuthenticationResponses.ResponseIds.LoginPrompt, new PromptOptions());
        }
```

```
var dc = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);

    if (dc.ActiveDialog != null)
    {
        var result = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();
        if (!turnContext.Responded)
        {
             // Start the Login process.
             await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MainDialog));
    }
```

These are the two code blocks regarding authentication where activity would be sent.

Edit 2/Solution:
Just wanted to follow up, I just figured out what I was missing. In the main bot.cs file, in OnTurnAsync, I needed to add this chunk of code and a piece in the constructor.
Constructor

```
_dialogs.Add(new AuthenticationDialog(_services.AuthConnectionName));
```

OnTurnAsync

```
if (!turnContext.Responded)
{
    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(AuthenticationDialog));
}
```

Comment: What happens, after you post the magic code, if you send another message? Does the bot continue at that point or has it stopped altogether? Also, can you post any relevant code so we help diagnose?

Comment: Steven, yes after I post back the magic code it shows the typing icon then just disappears. If I try to type more after that nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tested in any other channels?

Comment: No just the emulator